# If I use a class as a type parameter, how can I create an instance of this object within the parameterized class?

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, type-erasure

Say I hypothetically extend `LinkedList` to create a specialized sub-class called `GroceryList`.

`GroceryList` is parameterized with the class `GroceryItem` as its' type.

When I try to access `GroceryItem` as an instance within `GroceryList`, I get this compile-error in NetBeans:

```
incompatible types
 Required: GroceryItem
 Found:    Object
 where GroceryItem is a type-variable
   GroceryItem extends Object declared in class GroceryList
```

Apparently this is due to "type-erasure", and so far I'm unsuccessful in using a class as both a "type-variable" and a class in this way...

---

Here is a simple example:

```
public class GroceryList<GroceryItem> extends LinkedList {

    public GroceryList() {
    }

    public double getItemPrice(GroceryItem item) {

        // compile-error occurring here:
        return item.getPrice();
    }

    // compile-error occurring here:
    public GroceryItem getGroceryItem(String name, String brand, double price) {

        // ...finding the grocery item based on the parameters here:
        // ...

        return item;
    }
} // end of class
```

Comment: You're declaring a type parameter with name `GroceryItem`. That's hiding your `GroceryItem` type.

Comment: Can you show GroceryItem code? paste exact error? and just quick comment, getItemPrice could be static since you are not using anything from your own class there.

Comment: Try `public class GroceryList extends LinkedList<GroceryItem>`

Comment: Aha that's it, thanks @Reimeus! If you post this as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @porfiriopartida -- I'm meaning for `.getItemPrice` here to be an instance method. It will be more clear if I change the method to return an instance of type `GroceryItem`, I will change the code to reflect this.

Comment: @IanCampbell Yes, that is true, however, this is not instance at all, what if you receive a GroceryItem that is not in your current list? It will still work.

Comment: @porfiriopartida -- with the `.getItemPrice` method, the compile-error is actually on the `.getPrice()` method called within, and the same error mentioned above is generated on that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the `LinkedList` using the `GroceryItem` type

```
public class GroceryList extends LinkedList<GroceryItem>
```

or define the class as generic using:

```
public class GroceryList<T extends GroceryItem> extends LinkedList<T>
```

Comment: +1 Also, `class GroceryList<T extends GroceryItem> extends LinkedList<T>` would work, if the class needs to be generic.